# How to deal with nullable parameter in constructor?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes, `User` and `Team`. Each `User` can have a `favouriteTeam` but doesn't have to.

When creating a new user, a request comes through which contains the user's username and the `teamID` of their favourite team. If the user doesn't have a favourite team, the `teamID` value is `null`.

In `TeamRepository`, `findByTeamId` is called using the provided `teamID` value. If `teamID` is `null`, there are no rows in the table being queried with a `teamID` value of `null` so `findByTeamId` will return a null value. Hence `Optional<Team>` is required.

However, this causes problems when constructing a new `User`, because a parameter of type `Team` is required, not `Optional<Team>`. I have tried changing the type of `Users.favouriteTeam` to `Optional<Team>` but that causes a different problem (`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private long mygroup.tqbcbackend.model.Team.teamID] by reflection for persistent property [mygroup.tqbcbackend.model.Team#teamID] : Optional.empty; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private long mygroup.tqbcbackend.model.Team.teamID] by reflection for persistent property [mygroup.tqbcbackend.model.Team#teamID] : Optional.empty`).

What would be the best way of dealing with this problem?

*User.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserID")
    private long userID;
    
    @Column(name = "Username")
    private String username;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne(
            targetEntity = Team.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "FavouriteTeamID")
    private Team favouriteTeam;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, Team favouriteTeam) {
        this.username = username;
        this.favouriteTeam = favouriteTeam;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

*Team.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Teams")
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TeamID")
    private long teamID;

    @Column(name = "TeamName")
    private String teamName;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = User.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "favouriteTeam"
    )
    private List<User> fans;

    // constructors and getters and setters 
}
```

*TeamRepository.java*

```
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team,String>{
    
    public Optional<Team> findByTeamID(Long teamID);

}
```

Comment: "However, this causes problems when constructing a new User" => You forgot to tell us what problem you have. You could simply call `new User(someUsername, null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hence Optional<Team> is required.`, no, it is not (but convenient).

You may declare

```
public Team findByTeamID(Long teamID);
```

And you get a `(Team) null` back, if teamID not exists.

If you stay with Optional you may call the ctor of User with

```
new User(((Optional)team).isPresent()?((Optional)team).get():null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle it in the constructor of user

If(favourite Team == null) {
...
}

else{
...
}